# Создать regExp для валидации домена любого уровня

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Валидные адресы допустим:

```
asd.sd
asdasd.ru
www.dffe.ru
dfdf.dffdf.df.we
www.yandex.ru
www.asd.asd.asd.asd
```

Не валидные:

```
www
www.sdd.
asd.s
asd.sd.s
```

Начал делать так:

```
`/([\wЁёА-я\d-]{2,})\.([\wЁёА-я\d-]{2,})/`
```

Но потом ступор. Надо сделать проверку, что если потом есть точка, то после нее должно быть минимум 2 символа, если точки нет, то вернуть как есть. И эту проверку надо же как-то зациклить, ведь уровней может быть много?

Comment: По ходу дела: если вы в классе символов указали `\S` — то есть любой непробельный символ — всё указанное вами перед этим теряет смысл, так как буквы и цифры включены и так в `\S`. Вдобавок `\d` включено в `\w`.

Comment: суть не меняется, убрав /S я его поставил для того чтобы была валидации на пробеле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```js
const valid = [
  'asd.sd',
  'asdasd.ru',
  'www.dffe.ru',
  'dfdf.dffdf.df.we',
  'www.yandex.ru',
  'www.asd.asd.asd.asd',
];

const notValid = [
  'www',
  'www.sdd.',
  'asd.s',
  'asd.sd.s',
];

const re = /^([\wёa-я-]{2,}\.)+[\wёa-я-]{2,}$/i;

console.log(
  valid.map(testCase => re.test(testCase))
);

console.log(
  notValid.map(testCase => re.test(testCase))
);
```

Comment: @Andrew Ок, изменил ответ под это требование.

Comment: день убил на регулярки, пытался через позиционную проверку, а оказалось так просто... спасибо большое)

Comment: @Andrew Ну, может и не убили, а приобрели полезный опыт)

Comment: да буду практиковаться больше) а как мне допустим еще проверку на пробел ввести? типа [^\s]

Comment: @Andrew Вы имеете в виду проверку на отсутствие пробела? Но его ведь и так нет в перечне допустимых символов от начала до конца строки, поэтому с пробелом всё будет забраковано само по себе.

Comment: я думал, \w подразумевает и пробел)

Comment: Нет, он подразумевает только основные латинские буквы, арабские цифры и нижнее подчёркивание: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#types